# How to add customer login details to Firebase?

Tags: flutter

I need to use Firebase as a database, I am using login plugin, need to add the customer login details to Firebase. I completed the Firebase setup.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login/flutter_login.dart';
import 'package:myvoapp/main.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

const users = const {
  'dribbble@gmail.com': '12345',
  'hunter@gmail.com': 'hunter',
};

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Duration get loginTime => Duration(milliseconds: 2250);

  Future<String> _authUser(LoginData data) {
    print('Name: ${data.name}, Password: ${data.password}');
    return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
      if (!users.containsKey(data.name)) {
        return 'Username not exists';
      }
      if (users[data.name] != data.password) {
        return 'Password does not match';
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  Future<String> _recoverPassword(String name) {
    print('Name: $name');
    return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
      if (!users.containsKey(name)) {
        return 'Username not exists';
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterLogin(
      title: 'Myvo',
      onLogin: _authUser,
      onSignup: _authUser,
      onSubmitAnimationCompleted: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyApp(),
        ));
      },
      onRecoverPassword: _recoverPassword,
    );
  }
}
```

I need to implement **sign-in** method in firebase authentication. where to add firebase authentication in this code

Answer (score 1):

In the _authUser method, before `return`